# Why does hibernate save two @OneToMany lists in one table?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Imagine having following simplified code using Hibernate and JPA:

```
@Entity
class C {
    @Id @GeneratedValue public long id;
}

@MappedSuperclass
abstract class A {
    @Id @GeneratedValue public long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<C> list1;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<C> list2;
}

@Entity
class B extends A { }
```

Using a PostgreSQL database, this leads to a table `b_c` with columns

```
b_id | list1_id | list2_id
```

Now, trying to persist any `B` leads to following exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: NULL-Wert in Spalte „list2_id“ verletzt Not-Null-Constraint
Detail: Fehlgeschlagene Zeile enthält (779, 827, null).
```

Which roughly translates to
`NULL-Value in column "list2_id" violates Non-Null-Constraint. Contents: (770, 827, null)`

**Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?**
Merging the lists into one is not an option. Using Sets instead does not change anything.

Comment: how is C mapped?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski failed with the naming, sorry. Edited. My concrete implementation does not use any more or different annotations.

Comment: May be your 'list2' contain some `null` value, like it's written in the error massage... `NULL-Value in column "list2_id" violates Non-Null-Constraint. Contents: (770, 827, null)`

Comment: @Zorglube I checked at any point I could. list2 is always an empty LinkedList.

Comment: are you aiming at having the b_c linking table.. or you want to actually avoid it?

Comment: Use the JoinTable annotation, to tell JPA which join table you want to use for each of the list.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I would prefer to have two tables (for list1 and list2) for *every* class that extends A (so, two tables each).

Comment: @JBNizet I can't see how to use a generic name for the JoinTable annotation that creates two tables per subclass

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AssociationOverrides.html

Comment: @JBNizet Is there a way to create a new entity without adding the override annotation for every entity? The whole design goal of this is to minimize the overhead of creating new entities.

Comment: AFAIK, no. What exactly are reall A, B, C and other subclasses? What are these two lists? Maybe the design is the problem, but we can't say with what you posted.

Comment: C represents a serializable listener = callback function that has to be able to be associated with an entity at runtime. A represents an abstract superclass for all entities providing 'events' (calling all listeners on change or deletion). List1 contains all onUpdate listeners, while List2 contains all onDelete listeners.

Comment: @JBNizet when I give up on having 2 tables per entity, just using an `@JoinTable` annotation works just fine, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the unidirectional `@OneToMany` association. You need to first determine if your association is unidirectional or bidirectional.

If your association is unidirectional then you need to use `@JoinColumn` to fix the extra join table problem. If your association is bidirectional, then you will rely on the `@ManyToOne` side to propagate all entity state changes, with the use of `mappedBy` on the `@OneToMany` side. You can find good explanation about different ways of `@OneToMany` association [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).