# Hibernate OneToMany in MappedSuperclass fails with Null Constraint Violation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Based on [Why does hibernate save two @OneToMany lists in one table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115993/why-does-hibernate-save-two-onetomany-lists-in-one-table)

Imagine having following simplified code using Hibernate and JPA:

```
@Entity
class D {
    @Id @GeneratedValue public long id;
}

@MappedSuperclass
abstract class A {
    @Id @GeneratedValue public long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "listcontents")
    public List<D> list1;
}

@Entity class B extends A { }
@Entity class C extends A { }
```

This leads to a join table that looks like this:

```
b_id | d_id | c_id
```

where `d_id` refers to an item from my list and the other ids refer to instances of the according implementing class. Problem: both `b_id` and `c_id` are NON_NULL, therefore throwing an exception as soon as hibernate tries to load any class that extends `A`:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: NULL-Wert in Spalte „b_id“ verletzt Not-Null-Constraint
Detail: Fehlgeschlagene Zeile enthält (null, 1114, 779).
```

Which roughly translates into

```
Error: NULL-value in column "b_id" violates Non-Null-Constraint. Contents: (null, 1114, 779)
```

since an object of class `B` does not have a reference to a `C`, obviously.

**How do I make this work?** *(each class that extends `A` should have a persistent unidirectional reference to a `List<D>` without writing a single character of extra code in the extending class)*

I can freely change IDs and annotations to my liking, as long as it's in classes `A` or `D`.

Comment: How exactly is this different from the original question? The short answer is you cannot reuse a join table. Do you absolutely need to define a custom join table name? A join table is the default way JPA maps unidirectional one-to-many associations anyway, so just drop `@JoinTable` altogether.